# Injectivity of map $f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(2)\rightarrow B$

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra

I have oneissues with this problem

"Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/(2))\rightarrow B$ a map of abelian groups, then $f$ is injective if and only if $f(e_{1})$ is free torsion and $f(e_{2})\not=0$ where $e_{1}=(1,0)$ and $e_{2}=(0,1)$"

For the part $(\Rightarrow)$ I proved it by proving the contrapositive and I only needed check two cases when  $f(e_{2})=0$  and when  $f(e_{1})$ is not free torsion. In both cases I can give two different elements whose images are equal and thus the function is not injective.

My question is about the direction $(\Leftarrow)$ I can not see how to check that argument. I tried by contradiction but but I have cases where I am not sure how to do it.

Any suggestion would be great!

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

Take an element $\;x=m(1,0)+n(0,1)=(m,n)\in\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ , then

$$x\in\ker f\implies 0=fx=mf(1,0)+nf(0,1)\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;m,n\in\Bbb Z$$

But $\;f(1,0)\;$ is a torsion free element in $\;B\;$, so it must be $\,m=0\;$ (can you see why?), and thus since also $\;f(0,1)\neq0\;$ , it thus must be $\;n=0\;$ , so in fact

$$x=(0,0)\implies \ker f=\{(0,0)\}\;$$

and $\;f\;$ is injective

Comment: For the question, If $m\not=0$ ,from $f(x) =0$ I will have that $f(1, 0) $ is a torsion element . I don't see why $n$ if $f(0, 1,) $ is not zero.

Comment: @Liddo Thats basically fine. If $\;m\neq0\;$ then we have a torsion free element $\;mf(1,0)\;$ , and since $\;nf(0,1)\;$ is torsion then $\;fx\,$ cannot be zero. Thus, it must be $\;m=0\;$ ...but then $\;fx=nf(0,1)\;$ , and since $\;f(0,1)\neq0\;$ it must be that $\;n=0\;$ and we're done.